# My App installed in internal Memory, android:installLocation="preferExternal"

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I cannot move my app to the internal memory, when i have installed from the Google PLay. However from Eclipse, while i was developing I could move it, and if I install directly from the .apk too.

I have others app installed in the SD cards.

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.pedrera.ginTonic"
     android:versionCode="14"
     android:versionName="2.7" 
     android:installLocation="preferExternal">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install):

> The application prefers to be installed on the external storage (SD card). There is no guarantee that the system will honor this request. The application might be installed on internal storage if the external media is unavailable or full, or if the application uses the forward-locking mechanism (not supported on external storage).

Comment: Ok, but what is a "forward-locking mechanism"? The app is installed by default in the intenal memory and I cannot move to the SD card.

Comment: @JaviPedrera: "but what is a "forward-locking mechanism"?" -- it is an old copy protection mechanism that, AFAIK, is no longer available.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but I don't have the answer.

Comment: you should better specify your question as I read and re-read and can't figure it out. CommonsWare quote seems more than adequate. The system will try to do it but there're no guarantees, that's it.

Comment: @JaviPedrera u dont have the answer ? read the above answer 2 times, then u may get ur answer.

Comment: I don't know the root of my problem and I don't know what i have to do to solve it.

Comment: @JaviPedrera: Do any other apps on this device allow moving to app to external storage? Perhaps the issue is the device, not the app. You might also try a full uninstall and reinstall of your app, if you set this attribute and have been upgrading in place (e.g., just running your app in Eclipse).

Comment: The problem is the app, because I have talked with other friends who has the app, and they can't move it to the external storage. I have others app in my SD card. In Eclipse, while i was developing I could to move it

Comment: @JaviPedrera: Your app installs fine to external storage on a Nexus S. By Android 4.2, the whole "install to external storage" is gone, as it is no longer needed, so Android 4.2 devices will not show your app as being movable to external storage, as no apps are movable to external storage.

Comment: I am using the same Android version that i used when i was developing. So I think that version is not the problem. Maybe is a option in the publish process, I am not sure.... But I think that I dont deserve the downvote!! ;)